# How does (constantly x) differ from (fn [& _] x)?

Tags: clojure, expression-evaluation

I'm using a multimethod to provide different functions depending on what "mode" my project is running in (it's a [yada](https://github.com/juxt/yada) api server, and should be able to run in `:dev`, `:prod` modes etc).

I'm using [`mount/defstate`](https://github.com/tolitius/mount) to provide a keyword:

```clj
(defstate mode :start :dev)
```

When I dispatch using `(constantly mode)`, I get errors but when I dispatch using `(fn [& _] mode)` it seems to work.

Aren't these two forms the same? Or is there some subtle difference in the way in which (or the time at which) they are evaluated?

Comment: Please add the error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [mount](https://github.com/tolitius/mount) if you have not started your states yet then their values are `DerefableState` objects.

By calling [constantly](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.9.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L1437) you first evaluate the value of `mode` and then call the `constantly` function with the value. This means that when you invoke the result of `constantly` it will always return the parameter of constantly despite the fact that you have changed it since. If you have not started your state before calling `constantly` then it will store the `DerefableObject`.

On the other hand with `(fn [& _] mode)` you evaluate the value of the `mode` var every time you call the function. If you have not started your states then it will also return a `DerefableState` but if you have then the result will be the expected keyword.

A simple solution is to put the dispatch function in a state too.

```
(defstate dispatch :start (constantly state))
```

Comment: Thank you, great explanation. Is it correct to say the `constantly` form closes over `mode`, as it exists at compile time, whereas the `fn` form evaluates `mode` at runtime?

Comment: `constantly` closes over `mode` not in compile time but the time it is invoked during runtime.

Comment: I tried putting dispatch into a `defstate` like you recommended, but am getting `mount.core.DerefableState cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn` from the `(defmulti fn-name dispatch)` line. I think I understand why this is happening. Did I misunderstand your suggestion?

Comment: hmm, it depends on how you use `dispatch` but probably the same as above: you use its value before Mount is started. Try using `#'dispatch` instead of `dispatch` maybe?

Comment: I settled on a semi-workaround: https://gist.github.com/jdf-id-au/419c83f119bad7b4981a168ab6d37b78

Answer (score 3):

I think for an alternate explanation, you could use side effects to highlight what the difference is.

Compare:

```
(def const-f (constantly (println "Hello!")))
Hello!
=> #'user/const-f

(def fn-f (fn [] (println "World!")))
=> #'user/fn-f
```

Just executing the first `def` causes `Hello!` to be printed, since the body of `constantly` is evaluated immediately. The second `def` however prints nothing since the body of the `fn` isn't evaluated.

When calling them though:

```
(const-f)
=> nil ; Prints nothing. Just evaluates to what println returned

(fn-f)
World! ; Prints now,
=> nil ;  then returns what println evaluates to
```

`constantly` isn't a macro, so it's arguments must be evaluated first. `fn` however *is* a macro, so it runs before its arguments are evaluated.